# Sorting in case of Sharding in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, sharding, nosql

I have Implemented sharding in mongodb when we shard a collection to two mongod shards on the basis of hashed shard key, so It does a parallel sort inside shards. After that, how it sorts the collection on the basis of _id? and what may be the other points of consideration? what are:

1. Limitation of hashed shard key?
2. what sort procedure mongo query router use to sort the records fetched from the shards?
3. Whether the query will be affected due to network latency?

Answer (score 3):

1. Not sure.
2. If you don't specify a sort, mongo will return records round-robin from the shards, which I assume means there is no guarantee of any specific ordering, or even reproducible order from query to query. If you have an explicit sort, the primary shard will perform a merge sort. See the [`mongos` docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/#sorting)
3. Of course.

(This is an old question but it comes up pretty high in Google results.)

Comment: From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/#sorting: "The mongos then merges the data from each of the targeted shards and returns the result document. Certain query modifiers, such as sorting, are performed on a shard such as the primary shard before mongos retrieves the results.". The wording "such as the primary" is a bit ambiguous... why don't just tell "... such as sorting, are performed on the primary shard before mongos retrieves the results" to make fully clear that the primary shard is the one executing the merging?

Comment: Moreover, explain() shows SHARD_MERGE_SORT stage in this case, but it doesn't specify which shard (either the primary or other) is doing the merge.